# Need 28% acetic acid from 98% glacial acetic acid

Tags: experimental-chemistry, safety, home-experiment

i need to make a solution of a 28% acetic acid, what i get is 98% glacial acetic acid. If someone could please guide me to make this solution.

I want to know the safety precautions i need to take when using 98% glacial acetic acid.

Also i would like to know safety precautions i need to take when using 28% glacial acetic acid.

Can i store it in PP narrow mouth bottles

How long will this solution stay good and also how to store it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A lot of the information you request is available with a cursory internet search. If you can narrow the scope of your query, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As @Todd Minehardt already stated, a lot may be found in the internet.

Beside common sense (incl. appropriate equipment and protective clothing) and requesting help from trained persons (teaching assistant in lab class, chemistry teacher, to mention a few) in case of doubts:  If the chemical is well known and is (commercially) of importance, where available, chemical suppliers provide both the chemical as well as safety relevant data (in material safety data sheets, [MSDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_data_sheet)).  Often these data are provided in more than one language, too.  As two examples, look-up catalogues by [Sigma-Aldrich](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog) or [Acros Organics](http://www.acros.com).  The wiki page mentioned above even mentions a dedicated search engine.

Sigma, by the way, compiled many useful data [here](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/chemistry/stockroom-reagents/learning-center/technical-library.html), where the [molarity calculator](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/chemistry/stockroom-reagents/learning-center/technical-library/molarity-calculator.html) is one possible answer to your third question. In your case, the final volume of the diluted solution is 3.5 times the initial volume of the concentrated volume to be diluted in water.

Fourthly, the diluted acetic acid may be stored (at room temperature) in a bottle of PP.  Charts like [this](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/polypropylene-pp-chemical-resistance-d_435.html) provide an overview. Do not forget to check it prior to use and then regularly for cracks or leaks, as for every container containing chemicals, and to store it safely according to your local law.